# Sorting an NSMutableArray by a key value throws exception

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I am trying to sort an `NSMutableArray` with the following structure:

```
(
{
    Code = "390954-150";
    Size = "35";
},
{
    Code = 790540MSO;
    Size = "30";
}
)
```

I am trying to sort basing on the Code value, the `NSMutableArray` is called `arrayProduct`:

```
//Sort array by Code
NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Code" ascending:YES];
[arrayProduct sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]];
//
```

However the above code throws the following exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

Comment: Please read the very excellent error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `arrayProduct` looks to be `NSArray`.

Try converting it into `NSMutableArray` and :

```
NSMutableArray *mutableProducts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrayProduct];
[mutableProducts sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]];
```

Comment: @MartinR: only by 5 seconds.  When I tried to upvote, your post was already deleted. :(

Comment: Or call `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` on the original array and reassign to the original `NSArray` variable.

Comment: ++ for both answer and comment.